# How to dynamically disable form submit button when using Bootstrap validation

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation, form-submit

I have a form that is validated using Bootstrap Validator http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/.

You don't see the form at first (display: none). When you get to the step where you fill out the form, the Submit button is enabled, although the form is not valid. 
However, if I display the form right away, the Submit button is disabled until the form is valid, as I want it to be. Does anyone have idea why is this happening and how to get it to work?

```
<div id="step0">
  Some code here that is visible in the first step
  <div class="row">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="step1();">Go to step 1</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="step1" style="display: none;">
  <form id="forma-klijenta" data-toggle="validator" method="post" action="test.php">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 form-right">
        <h3> Lični podaci </h3>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 form-group col-sm-6">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="ime" data-minlength="2" name="ime" placeholder="Ime" required type="text" value=""
            pattern="^[A-ZŠĐČĆŽa-zšđčćž]([-' ]?[A-ZŠĐČĆŽa-zšđčćž])+$"data-error="Ime je obavezno. Dozvoljeni specijalni karakteri su - i '." />
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="row form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>     

  </form>
<!--      Kraj forme za unos podataka -->
</div>
```

Comment: i cant see anything in your url!!!

Comment: Sorry, that's the validator's URL. Because there are some others that use Bootstrap as well.

Comment: Post your code that uses the validator.

Comment: yeah please post your code

Comment: Ok, I've edited the question and added some code.

Comment: I get that the form is not there so whatever jQuery code that looks for it won't find it. But I show it, I call validator() on it, and still, my Submit is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I worked around this:

- Removed style="display: none;"
- Added jQuery

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#step1").hide();
  });
  ```